# jquery ajax isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get user information by using twitter api. The jquery code is below :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetUser() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=id&include_entities=true&callback=?",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache:true,
                timeout:8000,
                success: function (json) {
                    alert("Successfull");
                },
               error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }               
            });
    }
    </script>
```

xhr.responseText:undefined
thrownError:[object Error]
And html code :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="GetUser();" />
```

Comment: This seems like a statement, not a question.

Comment: Have you included jQuery ?

Comment: do u get any alert message ???

Comment: @AspiringAqib  of course I have included jquery.

Comment: @Barmar This is a question which is asked "what is the wrong about it" !

Comment: You haven't said what it's supposed to do, and what is going wrong. If the error alert is happening, make it display the AJAX error message so you can see why.

Comment: I have fixed error function. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your URL is not correct. Instead of

```
user_id=id
```

in your URL you have to use a actual value for id (id is just placeholder in your case). For example:

```
user_id=82193320
```

which would give you the data for my twitter user (uwe_guenther) back.

You can easily lookup twitter ids here:

http://mytwitterid.com/

If you just want to lookup user data by screen name you could use:

```
screen_name=uwe_guenther
```

instead.

The Twitter API description can you find here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

I have attached a working example for looking up screen_name by user_id and user_id by screen_name here:

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/EvJBu/) with the following example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwe_guenther/EvJBu/

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='userIdTextField' type='text' placeholder='user_id'/>
    <input id='userIdSubmitButton' type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <div id='screenNameResultView'></div>
    <br>
    <input id='screenNameTextField' type='text' placeholder='screen_name'/>
    <input id='screenNameSubmitButton' type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <div id='userIdResultView'></div>
    <br>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#userIdSubmitButton').click(function (){
        var userId = $('#userIdTextField').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=" + userId + "&include_entities=true&callback=?",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache:true,
            timeout:1000,
            success: function (json) {
                alert("Successfull: screen_name=" + json.screen_name);
                $('#screenNameResultView').text("screen_name=" + json.screen_name);
                console.log(json);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("No Result");
            }
        });
    });

    $('#screenNameSubmitButton').click(function (){
        var screenName = $('#screenNameTextField').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + screenName + "&include_entities=true&callback=?",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache:true,
            timeout:1000,
            success: function (json) {
                alert("Successfull: user_id=" + json.id);
                $('#userIdResultView').text("user_id=" + json.id);
                console.log(json);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("No Result");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Url is wrong

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetUser() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=id&include_entities=true&callback=?",//this is wrong
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    cache:true,
                    timeout:8000,
                    success: function (json) {
                        alert("Successfull");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("cant search");
                    }                 
                });
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: "...user_id=id..."Always  user_id=id and this is string and send string Id to the server

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workin example http://jsfiddle.net/kMgES/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=noradio&callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 8000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0].name);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("cant search");
    }    
});
```

In this example the search is done by screen name. Take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show for all possible options.

Consider using this for error handdling

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
           // error handling  
        }
```

Comment: there must be some errors on your side since this is working on jsFiddle. Maybe you are missing jQuery.

Comment: I have included jquery in this way: <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: seems to be ok. Have you tried debugging the site? Do you have any errors? Try using Firebug.

Comment: the input was inside the form(runat=server).Now I take it off and it is working. Thank you.